# Matlab: output format with fprintf

Tags: matlab

I want to have a list of data in a text file, and for that I use:

```
fprintf(fid, '%d %s %d\n',ii, names{ii},vals(ii));
```

the problem in my data, there are names that are longer than other. so I get results in this form:

```
1 XXY 5
2 NHDMUCY 44
3 LL 96
...
```

How i can change the fprintf line of code to make the results in this form:

```
1 XXY        5
2 NHDMUCY   44
3 LL        96
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this before the start of the loop -

```
%// extents of each vals string and the corresponding whitespace padding
lens0 = cellfun('length',cellfun(@(x) num2str(x),num2cell(1:numel(names)),'Uni',0))
pad_ws_col1 = max(lens0) - lens0 

%// extents of each names string and the corresponding whitespace padding
lens1 = cellfun('length',names)
pad_ws_col2 = max(lens1) - lens1
```

Then, inside the loop -

```
fprintf(fid, '%d %s %s %s %d\n',col1(ii), repmat(' ',1,pad_ws_col1(ii)), ...
    names{ii},repmat(' ',1,pad_ws_col2(ii)),vals(ii));
```

Output would be -

```
1 XXY      5
2 NHDMUCY  44
3 LL       96
```

For a range `99 - 101`, it would be -

```
99   XXY      5
100  NHDMUCY  44
100  LL       96
```

Please note that the third column numerals *start* at a fixed distance instead of *ending* at a fixed distance from the start of each row as asked in the question. But, assuming that the whole idea of the question was to present the data in a more readable way, this could work for you.

Comment: Thank you very much Divakar :). there is a small problem when the value of the first column changes from 9 to 10 or from 99 to 100.

Comment: Very nice Divakar ... +1

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `char` to convert a cell array of string into a character array where all rows will be padded to be the length of the longest one.

So for you:

```
charNames = char( names ) ;
```

then you can use `fprintf` :

```
fprintf(fid, '%d %s %d\n',ii, charNames(ii,:) , vals(ii)) ;
```

Just make sure your cell array is a colum before you convert it to char.

Comment: Very nice! For the first column when it changes from 99 to 100, one can use this char array trick there with - `charIDs = char(strtrim(cellstr(num2str([1:numel(names)].'))))` and then use the `charIDs` instead of `ii`.